# Android Studio Stuck at Gradle Download on import project

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to import a project on Android Studio, I get a window with a progress bar and the header,

Building 'Project' Gradle project info.

However, there is no progress in the build for at least 5-10 minutes.
What should I do?

Comment: try to restart studio

Comment: You should wait. Because Android Studio downloads all the Libraries and Dependencies required for the project to build. More time will be required if the project has many libraries.